# How much have eastern Bieszczady Mountains changed over the last 30 years?

Tags: poland, mountains, trekking

I used to trek across the eastern [Bieszczady Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bieszczady_Mountains) 30 years ago when visiting Poland. It was awesome.

I am planning to be back (this time with my teen children) and would like to understand how much they changed. **I am not talking about nostalgia** but rather about the availability of food/housing on the mountains, and how much the tracks were made easier. Overall I am trying to understand how much change I can expect.

In other words, would the "me from the late '80s" be surprised if time transported to today, somewhere between Wetlina and Ustrzyki Gorne?

Comment: I love questions like these. Not your cookie cutter " I am flying and I want to know about security / luggage / transit / visa etc" problems.

Comment: @chx However as asked I would say that it is near impossible to answer as the OP is asking for a comparison between 30 years ago and now - and that requires a detailed knowledge of change over that period, a very good memory and an understanding of what would surprise the OP.  In reading between the lines IMHO the OP is actually asking "What is the current state of food/housing/tracks in the region so that I can better plan my trip".  Also probably better answered on Outdoors SE

Comment: @PeterM: no, I am not asking about logistical planning. I am trying to build expectations about what I will see - I am sure that there are readers of SE Travel who would have been walking there 30 years ago. What would surprise me is a tourist-oriented reorganization of the region that would bring hotels and plain roads on top of the mountains and therefore significantly change the population that go there (the beaches of SW France or Alps mountains is what come to my (French) mind)

Comment: Of course I have absolutely no basis for this, but I have always assumed the average age of a [travel.se] reader to be well under 30.